# How are the self-attention layer weigths updated?

Tags: natural-language, transformers, attention

I am trying to figure out how the updating of the weights in the self attention layer works.

I think I have some basic understanding of how the self-attention mechanism works, however it is really unclear to me how loss on the language modeling task (I'm considering CLM as an example, but I am interested in an explanation for any LM task) is used to update the weights in the attention layers.

From what I understand the state of the self attention mechanism should be considered "good" if the attention weights are "high" for tokens that are semantically correlated with the current token.
The back-propagation step, however, only has information on the predicted token probabilities, and whether it was the correct token or not. So how does this information get used to update the attention weights so that they ouptut large score for semantically related tokens?

Thanks!

Comment: “The back-propagation step, however, only has information on the predicted token probabilities, and whether it was the correct token or not.” —That’s not true. It has the entire structure of the loss function, so gradients can be computed.

Comment: This question isn’t specific to language models. It pertains to any (differentiable) probabilistic classification model.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy thank you for your comment. I am a little confused. If I am using categorical cross-entropy on the prediction vector out of a softmax with |dict| dimensions, I think I am giving a loss signal that depends on whether I am capable of identifying the correct probability of the next token. Is it not true? If so, how is that relevant to the attention weights?

Comment: Sort of. With probabilities, it’s not a matter of “whether” but “to which degree”. // Your predicted distribution over tokens is a function of the inputs, previously predicted tokens, and model parameters. The attention weights are computed as part of this function. You can compute the gradients (efficiently by backpropagation), then update the parameters accordingly.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I'm following the reasoning that the gradients propagated back will update the attention weights, as they are part of the entire computation graph of the model. What I am missing is an intuition as to how the difference in the predicted distribution of the next token is reflected on the attention layers. Maybe I should make an example to clarify: let's say that at time t the next expected token is token_14 and the argmax of the softmax is token_166. How does that impact the attention weights? Would it be different if it was token_177? What if it is actually token_14?